# Sound clips for an application?

Tags: audio, clip

I'm building a (closed source) chat client style application and I'm having a hard time finding sound clips to use for various notifications.  Basic chimes like when someone comes online or when a message is received.

http://freesound.org obviously has lots of sound clips, but I've been browsing through it for a least 45 minutes and and I don't think I'm going to find what I'm looking for (but I'm gonna keep browsing).

Is there anything like a famfamfam silk icon set of sound?

Are there professionally designed ones that you've used in the past that can be licensed for a reasonable price?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.audiosoundclips.com. It's new but the effects are quality.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.partnersinrhyme.com/) maybe useful.

Comment: I'll take a look through here, too, but it doesn't seem too different from freesound.org.  It's harder than one would think to find a sound pack for an application...